# Get most clear iplimage from the buffer

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

How can I get most clear iplimage among rest , using OpenCV.? When there is no training image to compare.

As a example there is a web cam input which move a hand. But when I stream this video ,I get 10 iplimages. But only 5th one is more clear. I want to filter that 5th one using openCV.

Its good to evaluate each and every iplimage (10 images) and assign rank using clearness of the images. Is there any way to do it so..?

I hope kindness support from your all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Several measures of 'clearness' or *blur* in pictures have been quantified in research papers. So what you're looking for probably is to estimate the amount of blur present in an image and then use it to decide whether it is to be discarded or not. I found [this](http://scien.stanford.edu/pages/labsite/2010/psych221/projects/2010/AdityaAnchuri/main.pdf) study to be quite helpful, gives a comparative overview of the different metrics of blurriness. Google Scholar's always there with a search string of `estimating blur in images` if you want to check other resources.

You could choose whichever method gives you the best results with your set of images, experimentally determining which threshold of the measure will be 'clear' enough. Or of course you could run the blur estimation on every frame and choose the one with the lowest blur.